# Javascript stopwatch automatically starting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript/HTML stopwatch on my page, but it always automatically starts whenever the page loads. I'm Java-illiterate, can someone tweak the code so that it only starts when the Start button is pressed?

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
start = document.getElementById('start'),
stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
t;

function add() {
seconds++;
if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
    }
}

h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9   ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

timer();
}
function timer() {
t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

Comment: Take out your calls to start the timer:
timer();
after your timer function.

Comment: Javascript != Java, they are two VERY different languages.

Comment: Java-illiterate!!!, Javascript has nothing like Java

Comment: Omg okay! I was unaware, hence the illiteracy haha

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `timer()` after the function definition.. remove that line:

```
function timer() {
t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
// timer(); // comment this line
```

Comment: sorry I didn't see the curly br.

Comment: One more question: any idea how to take out hours and add miliseconds?